# Django Cannot import name views

Tags: python, django, view

So I'm trying to get up to speed on Django for a side project by doing the "first Django app" thing at DjangoProject, but I'm getting this weird message when I try to set up views for the first time.

```
ImportError at /index
cannot import name views
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/index
Django Version: 1.5.4
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name views
Exception Location: /Users/Dev/Desktop/socialSignIn/socSignInLocater/polls/admin.py in <module>, line 2
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.2
Python Path:    
['/Users/Dev/Desktop/socialSignIn/socSignInLocater',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-1.1.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 3 Oct 2013 15:58:02 -0400
```

It says that the error is in my root/polls/admin.py on line two, and seems to complain about not being able to import "views". The problem is that I am not trying to import views in

```
admin.py

#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from polls.models import Choice
from polls.models import Poll
# admin.site.register(Poll)

class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 1

class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ["pub_date", "question"]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]
    list_display = ("question", "pub_date", "was_published_recently")
    list_filter = ['pub_date']
    sarch_fields = ['question']
    date_heirarchy = 'pub_date'

admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)

# admin.site.register(Choice)
```

The error message also indicates that the issue is the import call to the Choice model, but that doesn't call views either.

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date_published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Update:

```
#views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse
# from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("You found the Poll Index.")

#urls.py
from django.conf.urls.defaults import * #patterns, url
#
from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
)
```

UPDATE #2: 
Oddly enough if I comment out the entire admin.py file, and redefine the `from polls import views` to `import views` then it works, but in doing so I've killed my admin section. Any ideas?

Comment: do you have a `views.py` ?

Comment: Please include `urls.py` and `views.py`. My guess is that the problem is with importing the view associated with the `/index` url.

Comment: added the requested files

Comment: The warning [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial02/#start-the-development-server) implies that "you’re probably using a version of Django that doesn’t match this tutorial version".

Comment: Already checked for that. I'm on 1.5.4 and I'm using the 1.5 tutorial.

Comment: what happens if you leave stuff in the admin file and just change `from polls import views` to `import views`

Comment: Breaks on the admin file. For some reason any import from Models to Admin restricts me from importing views anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I "fixed" the bug although I don't know exactly why this works.

In admin.py I changed the imports from

```
from django.contrib import admin
from polls.models import Choice
from polls.models import Poll
```

to

```
import views
from django.contrib import admin
from models import *
```

Perhaps it has to do with file organization? Anyways, thanks for the comments guys.

Comment: For me it turned out that the error was in the views.py , rather than inside urls.py

Answer (score 1):

You have in your address bar:

```
http://localhost:8000/index
```

But your urls.py says:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
)
```

So, Django is actually trying to look up:

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

That's why it can't find the first URL.

Comment: Even with localhost:8000/index it returns the same error. That URL was just the last one that I tried before turning to SO. There's got to be something wrong with the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem:
On **Windows7**, IDE **IntelliJ IDEA**
in `models.py`
When imports were like:

```
from django.db import models

from django.utils import timezone
import datetime
```

I received error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Poll
```

When I changed imports (using code reformatting in IntelliJ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>) to:

```
import datetime

from django.db import models

from django.utils import timezone
```

Everything started working magically :)