# i can not import py module when i using python django

Tags: python, django

that'my first time to ask question here.
i'm learning django now, I start a project in virtualenv.

that's my file

[image]

when I trying from polls import views module under urls.py.

module picture

[image]

it shows : No module named 'polls'

I search for the python documents and tring to modify it like:
from . import views  or
from .polls import views

but it shows:Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

some people say it's sys.path problem.So I added a current sys.path in the virtualenv.
But it can not work either.
How to solve the problem ? ....

Comment: go through https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/ again, you are editing the wrong `urls.py`.

Comment: It needs to be `from .polls import views`, but you need an `__init__.py` in your directory (inside `djmysite` folder)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Cannot import name views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168265/django-cannot-import-name-views)

Comment: @hop already work, thank u bro!

Comment: @Tgs  the web is working while the fault is still exist now.  This fault does not seem to affect the web